# MySQL data in 15 Minutes Increments

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to create high charts time line graph for my school attendance but I get slightly different records appearing in my result.

The table that stores attendance is :

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Id | Date     |  AttendTime(varchar)
--------------------------------
1  | 20160815 |  7:51
2  | 20160815 |  7:53
3  | 20160815 |  8:01
-------------------------------
```

I am using following sql to get the data

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(Id) as Total 
FROM Attendance 
     WHERE Date = '20160815' AND
           HOUR(STR_TO_DATE(AttendTime, '%H:%i'))  <= HOUR(STR_TO_DATE('7:30', '%H:%i'))
```

And I should get 0 as there are none but I get 3 records. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: I would expect 2 records, as `7 <= 7`. The `HOUR` function would return 7 for 2 of the records and for the condition.. You may want to get rid of the `HOUR` function..

Comment: @Galz is correct: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/473ca5/2 -- Why should you get 0 results?  Perhaps you just should remove `hour`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply trying to see how many attendances were before 7:30, you do not need the `HOUR` function:

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(Id) as Total 
FROM Attendance 
     WHERE Date = '20160815' 
     AND STR_TO_DATE(AttendTime, '%H:%i') <= STR_TO_DATE('7:30', '%H:%i')
```

Comment: Thanks @Galz that is exactly what I ended up doing . Great !!